# how to get vector pointing in Laser direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, daydream

I need to shoot elements form the controller, so ideally they'd go in the direction of the Laser pointer you can see and move with the controller.

This is what I need:

```
GameObject controllerLaser;
controllerLaser = GameObject.Find("VRMain/GvrControllerPointer/Laser");

Debug.DrawRay(firingSource.transform.position, firingDirection * 50, Color.red);
```

I need that red vector pointing and moving exactly like the Laser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it..

```
GameObject controllerLaser;
controllerLaser = GameObject.Find("VRMain/GvrControllerPointer/Laser");

//The Laser GameObject has the Reticle as its child, so you can make a vector
//that goes from the controller position to the reticle
firingDirection = controllerLaser.transform.GetChild(0).position - controller.transform.position;

//For firing the bullet (bonus)
bulletRB.velocity = firingDirection * bulletVelocity;

Debug.DrawRay(firingSource.transform.position, firingDirection * 50, Color.red);
```